# won't add TabPage to TabControl

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I'm trying to add a tabPage to an existing TabControl named TabControl4
I went all over it with the Debugger and everything is fine, but it won't show the TabPage in the TabControl.
That's the code, Notice all the information being added to the TabPage is retrieved from a database so don't pay any attention to it, plus the software is in Hebrew so just ignore the Hebrew Strings.

```
Table = DataBase.OpenRecordset("AthInj")
    Table.Index = "PrimaryKey"
    Table.Seek("=", AthId)
    Dim day1() As String = Table.Fields("injDay1").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim month1() As String = Table.Fields("injMonth1").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim year1() As String = Table.Fields("injYear1").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim day2() As String = Table.Fields("injDay2").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim month2() As String = Table.Fields("injMonth2").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim year2() As String = Table.Fields("injYear2").Value.ToString.Split("^")
    Dim injs() As String = Table.Fields("inj").Value.ToString.Split("$")
    Dim treats() As String = Table.Fields("treat").Value.ToString.Split("$")
    Dim rehabs() As String = Table.Fields("rehab").Value.ToString.Split("$")
    For i As Integer = 0 To injs.Length - 2
        Dim tp As New TabPage
        tp.Text = "פציעה " & (i + 1)
        tp.Name = "inj" & i
        Dim bday1 As New ComboBox
        Dim bmonth1 As New ComboBox
        Dim byear1 As New ComboBox
        Dim bday2 As New ComboBox
        Dim bmonth2 As New ComboBox
        Dim byear2 As New ComboBox
        Dim da As Label
        Dim label1 As Label
        Dim label3 As Label
        Dim label4 As Label
        Dim multiText As New TextBox
        Dim ill As New TextBox
        Dim date2 As Label
        Dim rehabText As New TextBox
        da = setLabel("מתאריך:", "injda" & i, 17, 560)
        label1 = setLabel("הפציעה/מחלה:", "inj" & i, 133, 490)
        date2 = setLabel("עד לתאריך:", "date2" & i, 67, 560)
        label3 = setLabel("דרכי הטיפול:", "injtreat" & i, 187, 473)
        label4 = setLabel("דרכי השיקום:", "injrehab" & i, 326, 470)
        copyCombo(bday2, bday, i, 60, bday.Width, 71)
        copyCombo(bmonth2, bmonth, i, 230, bmonth.Width, 71)
        copyCombo(byear2, byear, i, 396, byear.Width, 71)
        bday2.Name = "bday2" & i
        bmonth2.Name = "bmonth2" & i
        byear2.Name = "byear2" & i
        byear2.SelectedIndex = byear2.FindStringExact(year2(i))
        bmonth2.SelectedIndex = month2(i)
        bday2.SelectedIndex = day2(i)
        copyCombo(bday1, bday, i, 60, bday.Width, da.Top + 4)
        copyCombo(bmonth1, bmonth, i, 230, bmonth.Width, da.Top + 4)
        copyCombo(byear1, byear, i, 396, byear.Width, da.Top + 4)
        byear1.SelectedIndex = byear1.FindStringExact(year1(i))
        bmonth1.SelectedIndex = month1(i)
        bday1.SelectedIndex = day1(i)
        setTextBox(ill, 138, 80, "ill" & i, False, ScrollBars.None, 400)
        ill.Text = injs(i)
        setTextBox(multiText, 191, 32, "treatText" & i, True, ScrollBars.Vertical, 399)
        setTextBox(rehabText, 330, 32, "rehabText" & i, True, ScrollBars.Vertical, 399)
        multilineToBox(treats(i), multiText)
        multilineToBox(rehabs(i), rehabText)
        With tp.Controls
            .Add(rehabText)
            .Add(ill)
            .Add(date2)
            .Add(bday2)
            .Add(bmonth2)
            .Add(byear2)
            .Add(da)
            .Add(label1)
            .Add(label3)
            .Add(label4)
            .Add(bday1)
            .Add(bmonth1)
            .Add(byear1)
            .Add(multiText)
        End With
        tp.AutoScroll = True
        tp.BackColor = Color.White
        tp.RightToLeft = Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes
        TabControl4.Controls.Add(tp)
    Next
```

Comment: The standard explanation for this is that you use the wrong Form reference.  Especially common in VB.NET when you use threads.  Something like Form1.Foo() does *not* use the form reference that the user is looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just knocked up a little test app with a blank form and then added a TabControl and named it tabcontrol1.

Then in the form load event added the following

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim textbox1 As New TextBox With {.Text = "Textbox 1"}
    Dim tabPage1 As New TabPage With {.Text = "TabPage 1"}

    Dim textbox2 As New TextBox With {.Text = "Textbox 2"}
    Dim tabPage2 As New TabPage With {.Text = "TabPage 2"}


    tabPage1.Controls.Add(textbox1)
    tabPage2.Controls.Add(textbox2)

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage1)
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage2)

End Sub
```

And everything worked fine.  I think the only bit you have wrong in your code is where you have TabControl4.Controls.Add(tp) instead of TabControl4.**TabPages**.Add(tp)

Comment: The little test app I knocked up worked fine.  Are you sure you are getting results back from the database?

Comment: Yeah, i watched over it with the debugger, the results are getting back and everything seem fine, may i upload to you the whole project for you to find up the problem?

Comment: it's in AthCard form, in getInj Sub.

Comment: i have another sub called getAchive, which is exactly the same, and it works

Comment: It took some fiddling around but I got it working by rebuilding the solution.

Comment: it's fine i've just needed to use TabControl2 instead of TabControl 4. The TabPage was added to the wrong TabControl